# Sorting Columns AlphaNumerically in LISTVIEW in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

We have WPF application, In which we are ListView in One form, 
We want to order item alphanumerically.

When we sort the columns it needs to sort alpha numerical EG

AW1
 AW2
 AW3

At the moment it is sorting

AW1
 AW100
 AW2
 AW200

So what need to be changed?

```
 if (lastDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
                    {
                        direction = ListSortDirection.Descending;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
                    }
```

And

```
   // get the sort property name from the column's information.
                string sortPropertyName = sortableGridViewColumn.SortPropertyName;

                // Sort the data.
                Sort(sortPropertyName, direction);
```

SORT function like this,

```
private void Sort(string sortBy, ListSortDirection direction)
    {
        lastDirection = direction;
        ICollectionView dataView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.ItemsSource);

        dataView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
        SortDescription sd = new SortDescription(sortBy, direction);

        dataView.SortDescriptions.Add(sd);
        dataView.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: I dont know how to check Alphanumeric, pls help.

Answer (score 0):

String comparison is done character by character from left to right.  So if you change your column names to **AW001**, AW100, **AW002**, AW200 your sorting will work just fine.